# Olap4j mdx query is taking too long to execute on SSAS cube

Tags: olap, mondrian, olap4j

While executing MDX query from olap4j through http services(msmpupm.dll) its taking too long. As a test the following query on predefined cube(adventureworksdb) is taking 3 seconds on ssas and 180 seconds from olap4j.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Freight], [Measures].[Extended Amount], [Measures].[Discount Amount] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ([Dim Currency].[Currency Key].[Currency Key].ALLMEMBERS * [Dim Customer].[Customer Key].[Customer Key].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [AdventureExampleCubeV]
```

I think the [Lot of events produced in SSAS (optimization)](http://sourceforge.net/p/olap4j/discussion/577988/thread/161c048e) thread is relevant and i tried it with suggested solution in the thread . and its working and taking 4 secs(without using formatter like(RectangularCellSetFormat)) but as suggested in thread its not a good solution.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Note: This is problem with SSAS as per above discussion thread.